# App-engine and Scala

Tags: java, google-app-engine, scala

I have a 2-part question:

1. Could you use Scala with Google's App Engine instead of Java?
2. (Assuming 1 is answered yes) Would it be advised?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here, my app:
[NSMatic](http://nsmatic.appspot.com/)

As to the 2nd question... I don't know why it just wouldn't be advised.

Comment: Nice. I don't know much about this new-fangled Scala everyone's talking about.